# ASP.NET: Having two modals in the same razor page act strange

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web, razor, bootstrap-modal

So i have this razor page that has two modals, each with a different form uploading to a different model.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal-ticket" @*data-url="@Url.Page('/ProjectPages/ProjectPage/@counter')"*@>
        <span class="plusCircle">+</span> Add ticket
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal-participant" @*data-url="@Url.Page('/ProjectPages/ProjectPage/@counter')"*@>
        <span class="plusCircle">+</span> Add
    </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="add-ticket" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addTicketLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addTicketLabel">Create Ticket</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body modal-body2">
                <form asp-page-handler="TicketModalPartial">
                    <input name="IsTicketValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="TicketModel.TicketName">Title</label>
                        <input asp-for="TicketModel.TicketName" class="form-control" placeholder="Ticket1" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="TicketModel.TicketName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group " style=" padding-bottom:17px;">
                        <label asp-for="TicketModel.TicketDescription">Description</label>
                        <textarea asp-for="TicketModel.TicketDescription" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="There is something wrong"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="TicketModel.TicketDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label asp-for="TicketModel.TicketAsigneeId">Assign this ticket to</label>
                        <select id="TicketType" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" asp-for="TicketModel.TicketAsigneeId.Id" asp-items="Model.Items" style="width: 465px;">
                            <option>Select asignee (optional)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="center" style="padding-left: 55px; padding-bottom:0px;">

                        <p style=" word-spacing: 105px; margin: 2px">Type Priority  Status</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center">
                        <div class="btn-group " style="padding-left: 14px;">
                            <select id="TicketType" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" asp-for="TicketModel.Type" asp-items="new SelectList(Model.aType)" style="width: 135px;"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group " style="padding-left: 14px;">
                            <select id="TicketPriority" class="form-control" asp-for="TicketModel.Priority" asp-items="new SelectList(Model.aPriority)" style="width: 135px;"></select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="btn-group" style="padding-left: 14px;">
                            <select id="TicketStatus" class="form-control" asp-for="TicketModel.Status" asp-items="new SelectList(Model.aStatus)" style="width: 135px;"> </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="add-participant" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addParticipantLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addTicketLabel">Add Participant</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body2 ">
                <form asp-page-handler="ParticipantModalPartial">

                    <input name="IsParticipantValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label asp-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectParticipants">Project participants</label>
                        <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" asp-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectParticipants" asp-items="Model.Items.Where(p => Model.ProjectParticipantsList2.All(p2 => (p2.UserId.ToString() != p.Value.ToString())))" style="width: 470px;"></select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="ProjectsModel.ProjectParticipants" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery:

```
 $(function () {
$('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal-ticket"]').click(function (event) { // cand butonul cu ajax-modal este apasat
        var url = '/ProjectPage/0';      // url-ul partial-viewului
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            console.log("test")
            $('#add-ticket').modal('show');       
        });
    });
    $('#add-ticket').on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {   
        console.log("action");
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form'); //in the modal find the form
        var dataToSend = form.serialize();               // creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');            // atributul formului
        $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {        // save to db and then hide
            var newBody = $('.modal-body', data); //
            $('#add-ticket').find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody); // display the necesary validation
        //    var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True'; // if validation is succesfull
            var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsTicketValid"]').val() == 'True'; // if validation is succesfull
            if (isValid) {
                $('#add-ticket').modal('hide');// hides the modal after we are done
                location.reload();   // reloads the page after creation
            }
        });
    });
    $('#add-ticket').on('click', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', function (event) { // cand close este apasat
        $('#add-ticket').modal('hide');            /// ascundem modalul
    });});
$(function () {
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal-participant"]').click(function (event) { // cand butonul cu ajax-modal este apasat
        var url = '/ProjectPage/0';      // url-ul partial-viewului
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            console.log("test")
            $('#add-participant').modal('show');
        });
    });
    $('#add-participant').on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {   // cand save este apaat
        console.log("action");
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form'); //in the modal find the form
        var dataToSend = form.serialize();               // creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');            // atributul formului
        $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {        // save to db and then hide
            var isValid = $('#add-participant').find('[name="IsParticipantValid"]').val() == 'True'; // if validation is succesfull
            if (isValid) {
                $('#add-participant').modal('hide');// hides the modal after we are done
                location.reload();   // reloads the page after creation
            }
        });
    });
$('#add-participant').on('click', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', function (event) { // cand close este apasat
    $('#add-participant').modal('hide');            /// ascundem modalul
    });});
```

The first modal(ticket) worked fine at first, however after i added the second one(which works) the first stopped working. I found out that if i delete

```
*  [BindProperty]
        public ProjectsModel ProjectsModel { get; set; }*
```

the first modal works again, but i need the property for the second modal. Can someone enlighten me on wtf is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was not at all related to either the html or the jquery and was in fact **[BindProperty]** that was causing it.
So instead of using

```
[BindProperty]
    public ProjectsModel ProjectsModel { get; set; }
 [BindProperty]
    public TicketsModel TicketModel { get; set; }
```

i only used

```
  //[BindProperty]
    public ProjectsModel ProjectsModel { get; set; }
   // [BindProperty]
    public TicketsModel TicketModel { get; set; }
```

and instead, i did the binding inside onPost:

```
 public IActionResult OnPostTicketModalPartial([Bind("TicketName, TicketDescription, TicketAsigneeId,Type,Priority,Status")] TicketsModel TicketModel, int id)
 public IActionResult OnPostParticipantModalPartial([Bind("ProjectParticipants")] ProjectsModel ProjectsModel, int id)
```

and now everything works fine